# How to enable access to Clipboard when application is in background in uwp application

Tags: uwp, background, drag-and-drop, clipboard

I am getting Access denied error while copying data from the clipboard. This is maybe because sometimes my application goes in the background. Is there any workaround to enable access to the clipboard while its in background

DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();

Answer (score 1):

No, for privacy reasons UWP apps are not allowed to access the clipboard when in the background. If you build a Full Trust app (aka Centennial or Desktop Bridge) then it can access the clipboard in the background.

Comment: While dragging an image from WPF I am copying the image to Clipboard and then dropping it to UWP application, but sometimes it gets failed and the error it shows is access denied.

Comment: Is there a reason for trying to copy it? The drop operation should give you the data.

Comment: No. actually I need to drag an image from wpf and drop it to uwp application but as cross-platform drag and drop is not possible, I took an alternative by copying image to clipboard and then later fetch it

Comment: Can you share the code that isn't working? And / or maybe close this question and ask a new one about "why drag and drop isn't working"?